# How do I click on button in a new tab? Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to open a new tab in selenium. Additionally, I would like to click on a button that appeared in the new tab.

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('')")
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

This my code. The problem is that with "driver.find_element_by_xpath()" I can only click on elements that are on the main window.

Comment: create minimal working code which we could run. Maybe you have to open tab in different way - so it will be activate - and then it will work.

Comment: Welcome to SO please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly